# Shouldn't particles lose energy after collisions?

Tags: forces, energy, pressure, temperature

I read that particles gain energy after collisions i.e they hit a wall, but bounce back faster than before. According to my common sense, shouldn't the particle lose energy, as hitting the wall would consume its energy.

How does it gain energy from collisions?
And how do they constantly bounce around without running out of energy?

Sorry if the answer is really obvious, but this question has bugged me for a long time. I could not find a good answer on the internet. Could anyone explain it simply please?

Comment: Where did you hear that?

Comment: Richard Feynman's Six Easy Pieces

Comment: Feynman did not say that at all. I think you misread. Can you tell me the specific location in the book, and I'll explain it if you want. Thanks.

Comment: What's the temperature of this wall?

Comment: @PM2Ring You think the particles will absorb heat from the wall during a collision?

Comment: Cold gas hitting a hot wall will tend, on average, to acquire energy and warm up the gas...

Comment: Yes, but here we are talking about individual collisions. Not about many particles being heated up, in which case their average kinetic energy increases.

Comment: If we have a container of gas in a constant temperature environment, then the gas & container will be in thermal equilibrium, and there will be no net change in the mean kinetic energy of the particles when they collide with the walls of the container. But if the temperature of the environment changes, the system will move to a new equilibrium.

Comment: However, the gas molecules have a range of energies (typically a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution), with some particles slower than average, and some faster, with very few particles actually having the average KE. So in most collisions, there will be a change in KE.

Comment: Yes, but if you averaged energies over the _entire_ gas, the collisions will be elastic (usually, but never super-elastic).

Comment: You're right. I misread it, thanks you so much for the answers!

Comment: Your welcome. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the wall you are talking about is moving, the particle will never gain energy. A collision can either be elastic or inelastic, but *never super-elastic* (where the total kinetic energy increases).

Of course if a wall *is* moving toward the colliding particle, momentum will be transferred to it from the wall thereby increasing its kinetic energy. As Feynman specifically stated in the text you referred to in the comments,

"*What happens when an atom hits the moving piston? Evidently it picks up speed from the collision. You can try it by bouncing a ping-pong ball from a forward-moving paddle, for example,
and you will find that it comes off with more speed than that with
which it struck.*"

I think that is where your misinterpretation arises.

The total energy after a collision will never increase, and in fact, the total energy of any (isolated) system remains the same. This is a fundamental property of nature called [conservation of energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy). In the case of inelastic collisions, kinetic energy is usually lost to friction, sound, heat etc.

Comment: So conservation of energy is responsible for it?? As energy can not be created or destroyed? That clears it up a lot. Thank you man

Comment: That's OK. Good luck.

Comment: @josephh Out of curiosity is there anyway the system’s energy will increase while mass of some particle’s decreases?

Comment: So after some time, the system will keep on losing energy due to friction, sound, heat etc? What happens then? Do the particles just stop moving?

Comment: If a collision can never be super-elastic, then how does a hot wall ever conduct heat to an adjacent, cooler gas?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. How does that have anything to do with super-elastic  collisions?

Comment: Which one gains energy if you can't tell if its the wall or the particle that moving?

Answer (score 1):

I am quoting the excerpt from Six Easy Pieces that OP is presumably referring to in the comments.

> Suppose that the piston moves [inward] so that the atoms are slowly compressed into a smaller space. What happens when an atom hits the moving piston? Evidently[,] it picks up speed from the collision. You can try it by bouncing a ping-pong ball from a forward-moving paddle, for example,
> and you will find that it comes off with more speed than that with
> which it struck. (Special example: if an atom happens to be standing still and the piston hits it, it will certainly move.) -- *Richard Feynman ("Six Easy Pieces". Chapter $1$, Atoms in Motion. Page $8$.)*

In the context, it is self-explanatory as to why Feynman is saying what he is saying. The particles gain energy after colliding with the wall because the wall is moving (against the pressure created by the collisions of the particles of the gas against it) and the mechanical energy that is being used to drive the wall is converted into the (microscopic) kinetic energy of the particles.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw a ball against a stationary wall, you are right. Some of the kinetic energy of the ball will be converted to heat. The ball will bounce back with less energy.

An ideal ball bouncing off an ideal wall can have no loss. In that case the ball bounces back with the same energy.

But think of a ping pong ball bouncing off a paddle, or a golf ball bouncing off a club. If the "wall" is moving, the ball can gain energy. The "wall" will lose some.